# RavenDB insert performance

Tags: nosql, ravendb4

We have a requirement to quickly store large volumes of data, something on an order of 100k records at once. I'm evaluating RavenDB, and it seems like the metrics I'm getting are rather low - it takes about 2.5-3 seconds to store 10k of records.

The code is pretty much straight from the documentation:

```
 using (IDocumentStore store = new DocumentStore { Urls = new[] { "http://localhost:8080" }, Database = "xxx" })
{
    store.Initialize();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())  
        {
            var things = DataGenerator.GenerateListOfThings(); // gets me a 10k objects
            foreach (var thing in things)
            {
                session.Store(thing);
            }
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

"Thing" objects is a flat object with about 20 properties, nothing special about it.

I've also tried saving in chunks of 1000 entities, which improved the run times by about 10%, and bulk load, which with similar results.

Raven runs in docker container with default config on a machine with i7, SSD and 16Gb of ram. 
Documentation says about "150k writes on commodity hardware" but I'm not seeing anything close to it.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You'll get better performance with Bulk Insert, see here:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/Csharp/client-api/bulk-insert/how-to-work-with-bulk-insert-operation#example

Parallelizing the inserts will get even better performance.

Comment: I've tried it. It is faster, but it's not a huge difference (goes from 3 seconds down to 2.3 seconds/10k objects). Switching to "fastest" compression level drops the time down to 1.7 seconds or so. I need something that's at least 10x faster, though.

Comment: Can you parallelize the insert performance?

`Parallel.For(0, 10, (_) =>
{
using (var bulkInsert = store.BulkInsert())  
        {
            var things = DataGenerator.GenerateListOfThings(); // gets me a 10k objects
            foreach (var thing in things)
            {
                session.bulkInsert(thing);
            }
        }
});
`